# How to collect data inside a loop using flow and coroutines

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I'm new to using flow and coroutines and I would like you to help me with the following problem:

I have the `useCases.getScheduleList()` and `useCases.getScheduleDetails()` methods that return a Flow. And I need to call `useCases.getScheduleList()` to get the schedule list and then call `useCases.getScheduleDetails()` for each item in the schedule list. Following is my attempt:

```
    viewModelScope.launch {
        useCases.getScheduleList().collect {
            val scheduleList = it
            val schedulesWithDetails = arrayListOf<ScheduleWithDetails>()

            for (schedule in scheduleList) {
                launch {
                    useCases.getScheduleDetails(schedule.code)
                        .collect { detail ->
                            schedulesWithDetails.add(
                                newScheduleWithDetail(
                                    schedule,
                                    detail.body
                                )
                            )
                        }
                }
            }

            // updateUI is called before collect add items to schedulesWithDetails
            updateUI(schedulesWithDetails)
        }
    }
}
```

In the code above I can collect the listing and also collect the detail of each item in the listing and add the results to my `schedulesWithDetails` but I cannot use `schedulesWithDetails` with the data already added because the `updateUI()` method does not wait for the collect process to finish in then be executed.

Can anyone help me with ideas/suggestions for this problem?

Comment: aren't you suppose to handle the `getScheduleDetails` inside the `ViewModel` ?

Comment: Yes, and I am doing this in the viewModel and I am also using viewModelScope.launch

Comment: It's a huge red flag that you have a function called `updateUi` in your ViewModel. Referencing any UI from a ViewModel causes memory leaks. You should expose an appropriate flow for your Fragment/Activity to collect on its own.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your observation. But the `updateUI` method was just an example that I put to represent that someone will use the result of `schedulesWithDetails`. I actually update the view through livedata.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this out:

```
viewModelScope.launch {
    useCases.getScheduleList().map { scheduleList ->
        scheduleList.map { async { useCases.getScheduleDetails(it).first() } }.awaitAll()
    }.collect { schedulesWithDetails ->
        updateUi(schedulesWithDetails)
    }
}
```

Comment: It worked ! Thank you very much for the suggestion. Do you know how I could run the `useCases.getScheduleDetails(schedule.code)` calls in parallel ?

Comment: Yes, use `async` inside the map
Then use `awaitAll()` after the map

Comment: Thank you very much, that was exactly what I was looking for :D